# How to export own objects using expdp without special privileges?

Tags: oracle, export, expdp

As per [this post](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1068303?start=0&tstart=0) on Oracle forums expdp can be used to export your own schema without any special privileges:

> It all depends on what you want that user to be able to export/import.
>   If all that use is exporting/importing is their own objects, then they
>   don't need any raised privs. If you want that user to be able to
>   export objects owned by other schemas, then they would need the
>   exp_full_database and in order to import, they would need
>   imp_full_database.

However I just can't get it to work. Directory object is required to be specified otherwise expdp displays error:
`ORA-39145: directory object parameter must be specified and non-null`
But creating directories requires `CREATE ANY DIRECTORY` system privilege.

How then can I export my own schema as a normal user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirement to specify a directory object is only there with the new `expdp` utility. The older `exp` tool allows specification of an absolute path.

I was able to take a backup using `exp` without having any special privileges and without creating any directory objects, just using my username and password.

Though succeeded by `expdp`, `exp` is still included in recent versions of Oracle.

For example an `expdp` dump would look like:

```
expdp kshitiz/password@SID directory=DIR01 dumpfile=file.dmp
```

Where `DIR01` is the directory object a user with `CREATE ANY DIRECTORY` would need to create:

```
CREATE 
OR 
REPLACE DIRECTORY dbm01 AS '/tmp';
```

`exp` will accept the path directly:

```
exp kshitiz/password@SID file=/tmp/file.dmp
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating Directory Objects and Export/Import are two different operations. Directory Objects are owned by SYS.

> A directory object maps a name
>   to a directory path on the file system. DBAs must ensure that only approved users are
>   allowed access to the directory object associated with the directory path.
>   If you are not a privileged user, then before you can run Data Pump Export or Data
>   Pump Import, a directory object must be created by a database administrator (DBA) or
>   by any user with the `CREATE ANY DIRECTORY` privilege.
>
> #### Schema Mode
>
> A schema export is specified using the `SCHEMAS` parameter. This is the default export
>   mode. If you have the `DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE` role, then you can specify a list of
>   schemas, optionally including the schema definitions themselves and also system
>   privilege grants to those schemas. If you do not have the `DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_
>   DATABASE` role, then you can export only your own schema.

[Data Pump Export-Schema Mode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#i1007509)